# Uncaught ReferenceError: LazyLoad is not defined

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, referenceerror

I'm using this lazy load script: https://github.com/verlok/lazyload

As recommended there, I've added this script just before my `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(w, d){
        var b = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var s = d.createElement("script"); s.async = false;
        var v = !("IntersectionObserver" in w) ? "8.7.1" : "10.5.2";
        s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-lazyload/" + v + "/lazyload.min.js";
        w.lazyLoadOptions = {}; // Your options here. See "recipes" for more information about async.
        b.appendChild(s);
    }(window, document));
</script>
<script>
    new LazyLoad();
</script>
```

However, I'm getting the Google Chrome console error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: LazyLoad is not defined

I tried setting `s.async = false`, but that does not help.

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: try moving `new LazyLoad();` into `window.onload` function

Comment: Just use [auto initialisation](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload#async-script--auto-initialization)? You don't seem to need that instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the Object to your initial code exactly where you see the comment

> "Your options here. See "recipes" for more information about async."

You are mixing the Async and Sync Loading and execution of Lazyload.